# If a variable is something and another variable is something else do, PHP

Tags: php, variables, var

I'm doing some PHP traning, and wanted to make my own copy of "Rock, Paper and Scissors" and then I'd like to compare the results from the user and the computer, and I tried with this code:"

```
if($choice = 'Rock' and $pcSelect == 'Scissors'){

echo "You win!";

}
```

Plz help me,
Magn0053

Comment: This is a good place to start. http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning `'Rock'` to `$choice` with `=`.  You need to test equality with `==` like in the second conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Use && instead of and in your if

```html
if($choice == 'Rock' && $pcSelect == 'Scissors'){

echo "You win!";

}
```